# Puzzling ... why do most of my links, in ASP.NET MVC, have Length=4 appended to them?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Why does the following code:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("[Click Here For More +]", "Work", "Home", new { @class = "more" }) %>
```

render as:

```
<a class="more" href="/Home/Work?Length=4">[Click Here For More +]</a>
```

Where is that "Length=4" coming from?

Update

If I remove the `new { @class = "more" }`, I don't get that Length=4 parameter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've had this happen before.  If you look at the overload you're actually using it's probably not the one you want.

Try...

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("[Click Here For More +]", "Work", "Home", null, new { @class = "more" }) %>
```

Comment: Just came to this realization as well!

Comment: Yeah, this drove me nuts for about an hour before it hit me.

Answer (score 5):

I look at the overloads for ActionLink and changed the code to look like:

```
    <%= Html.ActionLink("[Click Here For More +]", "Work", "Home", null, new { @class = "more" }) %>
```

Added a "null" for the route values.  This seems to work.  Not sure though what this might affect.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a default value for "length" in one of your routes? If the wrong route is selected, use Html.RouteLink instead of ActionLink.

Comment: Good catch! IIRC the anonymous type gets converted to a Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a DebuggerVisualizer property! But that should not surface.

Anyways 'Length=4' looks suspiciously like an array (with 4 elements). Use the debugger to look for the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

The length=4 issue has popped up for me a couple times.  The culprit is usually a bad route, either in the definition or the link I am using.

I've gotten in the habit of always double checking those first.